# Netbeans refuses to recognise Eclipse workspace

Tags: java, netbeans

When I try importing my eclipse projects into my netbeans, according to this instruction (http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/import-eclipse.html), I get a message from Netbeans saying that my eclipse workspace is invalid. I've created a new workspace and created within it Eclipse projects, just to investigate if there really was something wrong with my initial workspace, yet still I get the same message from netbeans.

What do I do?

Comment: Are you trying to keep the eclipse project or migrate to netbeans? If you don't care about maintaining the eclipse project, then just create a new netbeans project and copy the source and add the other resources into it (jars etc...)

Comment: I'm trying to keep the eclipse project

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem, what solved the issue in my case was this:

**`File -> Import Project -> Eclipse Project`** (as you did before)

But now select **"Import Project ignoring Project Dependencies"** instead.

Comment: yes it works, but it will give problems in the future, as I got one already